# Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse

Tags: java, hibernate

i m new for hibernate and trying to run first application but getting this error:

"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
              "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

```
<hibernate-configuration>  

    <session-factory>  
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>  
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>  
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>  
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>  
        <property name="connection.password">prashant</property>  
        <property name="connection.driver_class"> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>  
    <mapping resource="employee.hbm.xml"/>  
    </session-factory>  

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: paste your hibernate.cfg to the question..

Comment: this is cfg file

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have some invalid xml in your hibernate.cfg.xml since it cannot parse.

Try to post the content in the file here so we can take a look at it.